# How to import Google Spreadsheet cells into a Google Document?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-docs

I would like to import (or better "*link*") data from a Google Spreadsheet (the Excel-like web app) into a Google Document (the Word-like web app).

I am not interested in manual procedures: I think copy-past would just work.

I need a table in Google Document to "import" data from a Google Spreadsheet.
And, as soon as I change the spreadsheet data and I later open the document, I would like to see the updated values *automatically*, if possible.

I think I could exploit Google Apps Script but am really new to this technology and hints or link to examples would be of great help. Of course any other working solution (if any) will be fine.

Comment: Unless there is an add-on that does this, its doable with apps script but too broad as a question.

Comment: @ZigMandel I was pretty sure I could do it with the Apps Script. I "just need"(tm) an example or  a pointer to some relevant information other than the generic Apps Scruipt online documentation. Thanks a lot, though.

Comment: Many addons do this. Search them. Question is too broad for s.o.

Comment: @ZigMandel If I was to upse addons, I would have not asked. I want to use no addon but "just" the Apps Script.

Comment: Then you need to write it. Your question is too broad and you already said you dont have experience coding. S.o. is not for handing your spec and expecting someone to write it, tey rentacoder.com or similar.

Answer (score 1):

[Sheets Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/)

[Docs Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/)

There are many helpful snippets and tutorials within the google scripts documentation (dig around in the listings on the left pane, click on the classes to see short usage examples).  You may even find something there that pretty much works 'out-of-the-box' for importing values from sheets into docs.

(Although, you may only be able to do things as 'automatically' as triggering an import function every minute or so, it won't be instantaneous).

Comment: If you know where such a snippet is, then please post it. I already spent hourse with Google but nothing useful has emerged. Probably my fault.